# Rewrite Javascript Function for ReactJS or Webpack Issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to embed draw.io Javascript source into ReactJS iFrame for a proof of concept app. I am new to Javascript and ReactJS so really just trying to figure stuff out. I am kinda stuck. I have the following structure:

1. diagram-editor.js (https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-integration/blob/master/diagram-editor.js)
2. display.js

display.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DiagramEditor from "./diagram-editor";

class Diagram extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Diagram</h4>
        <iframe
          src={DiagramEditor}
          onclick={DiagramEditor.editElement(this)}
          src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
          style="cursor:pointer;"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Diagram;
```

sample functions from diagram-editor.js

```
DiagramEditor.prototype.getElementData = function(elem) {
  var name = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase();

  return elem.getAttribute(
    name == "svg" ? "content" : name == "img" ? "src" : "data"
  );
};
```

This compiles however I get the following Webpack error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _diagram_editor__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default.a.editElement is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Do I need to edit the functions in diagram-editor.js. Please use the link above as it is a large file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add all `diagram-editor.js` file code? What do you export in that file?

Comment: Its exactly the same as the source in the link https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-integration/blob/master/diagram-editor.js

I have not changed anything.

You still want me to post?

Comment: This file is a plain JS implementation for browsers, it does not export anything. When you do `import DiagramEditor from "./diagram-editor";` there has to be an actual `export` inside the file you're importing.

Comment: ok that makes sense - how do I make the plain JS functions exportable?

Comment: You don't have to make it exportable. For the web, you just have to include/require and it will be global available like `import "./diagram-editor";` but I'm not sure how that will play with webpack.

Comment: oh ok thanks - how would i do that in the display.js file above?

Comment: Try that I suggested you like `import "./diagram-editor";` and then use `DiagramEditor` like you do or `window.DiagramEditor`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210809/discussion-between-db46-and-zekros-admines).